# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') ( fiz a verificação e nenhuma dessas procede)

Tags: python, machine-learning, regressão

estou trabalhando em um projeto de regressão linear em python, mas está havendo um problema no modelo.fit().
acontece  os seguintes erros:

## no código que eu coloquei aqui:

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

## quando eu tento ajeitar:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'e'

eu já procurei na internet, mas nada fala desse específico "e"
já tentei converter int(float(x)) e os números são todos floats no formato número.0, sem casas decimais. Alguns dos números são 0.0 e outros são valores altos. aqui está o código para análise:

```
mport pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
#imports
dataset = pd.read_csv('movies_metadata.csv')
data = dataset.columns
data =dataset[['title','budget','revenue','vote_average']]
#seleção dos dados
custo = []
for i in data['budget']:
    try:
        custo.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        custo.append(0)
custo = pd.Series(custo)
data['custo'] = custo
data.drop(['budget'],axis = 1)
data.dropna()
#modelo de machine learning
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import sklearn.metrics 
X = data['custo'].values.reshape(-1,1)
Y =data['revenue'].values.reshape(-1,1)
treino_x, teste_x, treino_y, teste_y = train_test_split(X,Y,random_state = 101,train_size = 0.27)
lista = [treino_x, teste_x, treino_y, teste_y]
modelo = LinearRegression()
modelo.fit(teste_x,teste_y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem acesso aos dados não consigo testar para ver se é isso, mas note que as linhas

```
data.drop(['budget'],axis = 1)
data.dropna()
```

não são operações *in-place*. Tanto [DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) quanto [DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) são métodos que retornam um novo `DataFrame`, o qual você não está assinalando a nenhuma variável.

Simplesmente assinale o `DataFrame` retornado de volta a uma variável, ex:

```
data = data.drop(['budget'],axis = 1)
data = data.dropna()
```

Ou adicione o argumento `inplace=True` para mudar o comportamento dos métodos, ex:

```
data.drop(['budget'],axis = 1, inplace=True)
data.dropna(inplace=True)
```